# Save As not recognizing delimiter

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I had a similar problem before when saving to .csv except all the data would be moved to column A. This time it is spreading it out across the columns at every comma. My list separator is set to semicolon because my descriptions contain commas. The solution when saving as .csv was setting Local to True. The code I use below is to save a .csv file as a .xlsx, so I can perform operations on it like deleting empty rows between data. Tried doing that to the .csv file and it didn't work. First image below is the .csv and the second one is what happens when I save it as .xlsx.

```
Dim CSVFILE As Workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set CSVFILE = Workbooks.Open("C:DOORS_COMBINED.grouped.csv") 


CSVFILE.SaveAs FileName:="C:DOORS_COMBINED.grouped.xlsx", _
FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False, local:=True



Workbooks("DOORS_COMBINED.grouped.xlsx").Close
```

[image: (Before) .CSV File]

[image: (After) .xlsx File]

Comment: You could try the [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) but from my own experience, it is better to have the file as a TXT extension. Using this to open something with a CSV extension seems to disregard certain options in favor of CSV-style defaults. Never had a problem opening TXT this way though.

Comment: So I would open my file as a text file and then save it as an Excel workbook? I'll give it a shot, Thanks @Jeeped

Comment: Tried Workbooks.OpenText method and it has the same outcome. Ill Post what i tried below.

Comment: Maybe get some redacted portion of your XLSX or CSV sent to a public file upload area and return here to edit your post and include the link. The problem is originating in the quotes used to represent *inches* being mistaken as *text qualifiers*. Some hands-on testing might produce a solution but I'm not retyping the data from your images (even if I could). The worse case scenario is that you will have to write your own export routine.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hliglz1cq18k9dh/DOORS.csv?dl=0

Comment: Hmm that's interesting that the quotes would do that. I would have never thought of that. See file in link above. @Jeeped

Comment: OK, the file already has problems. The `"` used for *inches* increments have been doubled up as `""`. This was likely due to bad interpretation of *text qualifies* somewhere between the origin or of the information and where it is now. While these problems are minor and could be repaired, it is band-aid post-processing of a problem that shouldn't be there to begin with. I've reread your narrative and I cannot figure out what stage of the whole process this CSV is coming from. The problem should be dealt with at the origin of the information; not repaired somewhere down the road after ...

Comment: ... bad processing. Please detail step-by-step what you are trying to accomplish, including the origin or the information and any steps that require conversion to and from XLSX ◄-► CSV. Essentially, what do you start with, what do you have to do, and what are you trying to ultimately accomplish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95634/discussion-between-geoff-and-jeeped).

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub XLSMSAVEBTN_Click()
Dim myfile As Workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks.OpenText FileName:= _
    "C:\Users\Geoffrey\Dropbox\DCS PROGRAM\FILES\1. QUOTES\3. PROGRAM FILES\DOOR QT REQUESTS\DOORS_COMBINED.grouped.csv"

Set myfile = ActiveWorkbook

myfile.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\Geoffrey\Dropbox\DCS PROGRAM\FILES\1.  QUOTES\3. PROGRAM FILES\DOOR QT REQUESTS\DOORS_COMBINED.grouped.xlsx", _
FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False, local:=True

Workbooks("DOORS_COMBINED.grouped.xlsx").Close
End Sub
```